# What's the quickest way to configure SQL Sever data types?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, import, sqldatatypes

I often have to import large tables in SQL Server, with dozens (sometimes 100+) columns which have their data types all over the place (usually stored as strings that need converting).

My current method is the view a sample of the values, determin the best data type and then use the following to change the column data types:

```
ALTER TABLE staff_mx ALTER COLUMN [First Name] varchar(50) 
ALTER TABLE staff_mx ALTER COLUMN [Preferred Name] varchar(50) 
ALTER TABLE staff_mx ALTER COLUMN [Middle Names] varchar(50)
ALTER TABLE staff_mx ALTER COLUMN [Last Name] varchar(50)
```

However when I have do this this between 50 - 100 times per table every time, I start think is there a better way of doing this?

I'm loading in flat files using the import wizard which often gives me an error if I specify the data types there (normally a weird date format it can't recognise that needs pre-manipulating before it can be stored as a date). Bulk insert isn't an option due my user configuration as set by the admin (they won't change it).

May not be a quicker way, but thought I'd ask. Thanks!

Comment: SSIS, along with most ETL tools, can help, too. When you use the tool to create your target table, SSIS will suggest data types. They're not always spot on, but it does a remarkably good job and saves your time on the easy ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't alter the table.  Load the data into a staging table, then do the transformations that you want for the final table:

```
select convert(varchar(50), [First Name]) as firstName,
       convert(varchar(50), [Preferred Name]) as preferredName,
       . . . 
into real_table
from staging;
```

This gives you the opportunity to do more complex transformations if those are needed.  You can also fix the column names in your staging data.

You can also pre-define the table and bulk load directly into the table.  However, that doesn't give you the opportunity to fix the data if that is necessary.

Comment: @PhilCollins You might also want to create a script or stored procedure to perform a sanity check on the staging table before doing the transformation. Typical checks might include: no duplicate email addresses, no birth dates in the future, ... .

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Gordon. I don't think this cuts down on the amount of work I have to do but I think it's a much better way of dealing with this task. @HABO, that's a great idea, not something I've done before but I could try and figure that out. Thanks both

Comment: @PhilCollins . . . Debugging load problems is much simpler if you can look at the staging data and figure out what the issue is.  The overhead for creating a staging table and copying the data is basically nothing when compared to the issues of debugging data problems.